# What is the flow return type of a React Redux connected component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

Consider the following function:

```
import type { ConnectedComponent } from "react-redux";

function createContainer(ComponentToConnect): ConnectedComponent<*, *, *, *> {
  // ... define mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentToConnect)
}
```

This gives me the following Flow error:

> class type: type application of polymorphic type: class type: ConnectedComponent This type is incompatible with the expected return type of ConnectedComponent

What is the correct return type to specify for a function that returns a redux-connected component like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're saying that createContainer is returning an instance of `ConnectedComponent<*, *, *, *>` whereas it looks like it's actually returning a class `ConnectedComponent<*, *, *, *>`. Try a return type of `Class<ConnectedComponent<*, *, *, *>` for `createContainer`.